# Finding revenue function then proving max revenue using optimisation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

Studying for a test and I am stuck on this question.

*To produce $$ units of some product, a company spends $() = ^2 + $ where $()$ is in dollars and $$ and $$ are real numbers. The product is sold at a price of $\$$ per unit.*

I am asked to find the revenue function and profit function and prove that for the maximum profit is when $x = \dfrac{p-b}{2a}$. 
I know that to find the revenue function you are meant to multiply $C(x)$ by the price of the unit, so does that make $P(x) = pa^2 + pbx - ax^2 - bx$?

If so I am not sure how to prove that for the maximum sales profit is when $x = \dfrac{p-b}{2a}$. I tried deriving $P(x)$ and got $P'(x) = 2apx - 2ax + bp - b$, but I don't know what to do.

Sorry for the formatting but I was unable to use images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a minor mistake was made while calculating the revenue. Revenue denotes the total sales of the product, so to get that figure you'll have to multiply $p$ with the number of units you are selling, i.e., $x$.

Hence your revenue would be $p * x$ for $x$ units produced, and the cost of producing those $x$ units would be $C(x)$. To get the profit, simple subtract the cost of production from the revenue, so that would be $(p*x) - C(x)$. Differentiate this with respect to $x$, and equate to zero to get the desired answer.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but wouldn't the profit be revenue - cost? eg. (p∗x) - C(x)?

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't too careful there, it should leave the intended answer unchanged though.

Comment: Thanks! That works out perfectly!